# Can Java omit sending some headers in HTTP requests?

Tags: java, http, optimization, java-me, http-headers

I'm using the HttpConnection class in Java to send HTTP requests.
How do I omit unwanted HTTP headers? like:

- User-Agent
- Accept
- Accept-Language
- Accept-Encoding
- Accept-Charset
- Keep-Alive
- Connection
- Referer
- If-Modified-Since

Comment: Did you mean a HttpURLConnection?

Comment: I'm actually using Java ME which has the HttpConnection class.

Comment: The problem side of it is that some devices don't allow you the change the standard headers like User-Agent, Accept, Accept-Encoding etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about HttpURLConnection, you can't do it. Once the header is set, it can't be removed.

Setting header to null or empty doesn't work. I tried this before on Java 5, it resulted invalid HTTP headers, like

```
Content-Type: text/html
User-Agent
Content-Length: 123
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, setRequestProperty in [URLConnection](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", null);
```